# Register receiver to handle notification button

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am trying to handle notification bar click on Android.
I created a class that extends BroadcastReceiver on my service.

```
public class SwitchButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("PlayService", "EVENT");
    }
}
```

Then i do:

```
switchButtonListener = new SwitchButtonListener();
registerReceiver(switchButtonListener, new IntentFilter("com.example.spotifytest.actions"));
Intent intentPlayPause = new Intent("com.example.spotifytest.actions");
PendingIntent pendingIntentPlayPause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentPlayPause, 0);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btPlayPause, pendingIntentPlayPause);
```

Nothing fires.. It works when i register the broadcast on the manifest, but i don't want my Listener class to be static.

Regards !

Comment: I try your code with my remoteviews in a notification and it works perfectly. What is your contentView ?

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT !

I was using an intentService.. Switched to service and it works.
Intent service does the work and ends.. that was the problem.